# How to consume an async method in api controller for Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, xamarin, asp.net-web-api2

I am quite new to Xamarin and using it in production normally I would do the following:

```
 // GET: api/Jobs
 public  async Task<string> GetJobs()
 {
     return await db.GetAllJobsAsync();
 }
```

My question is I want to return all jobs that an engineer has so I have this method in my data access layer then using my api to return the json from it but how Do I call the below in my Jobs API Controller

```
/// <summary>
/// Get All Jobs Assigned to the work person.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id"></param>
/// <returns></returns>

public async Task<string> GetAllJobsAsync(int Id)
{
        string json;

        using (FuelCallManagmentEntities _db = new FuelCallManagmentEntities())
        {
            var task = Task.Run(() => _db.Jobs.Where(w => w.EngineerId == Id).ToList());
            List<Job> alljobs = await task;

            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(alljobs, Formatting.Indented);
        }

        return json;
}
```

My question is also should I be returning json surely that is not that secure and what is the best way to secure passwords if using this type of way.

I wish I could be using azure but this has to be a secure hosted solution for our company.

I am also getting the above error when I attempt to run the code above.

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"S

Answer (score 3):

Refactor your method to:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllJobsAsync(int Id)
{
    using (var _db = new FuelCallManagmentEntities())
    {
        var alljobs = await _db.Jobs.Where(w => w.EngineerId == Id).ToListAsync();

        return Ok(alljobs);
    }
}
```

About the second question; It's a different question, which is off topic in SO...

As I know the standard today is to keep password in a `Hash-Salt` mechanism.
[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsIO0gxJF3g) explain this mechanism in a very good way.

BTW you should never return passwords or have mechanism to expose the passwords you store.

Comment: what is best then keep a local db of passwords on the persons phone its for a driver style app just for

Comment: @DavidB in the phone's secure storage, you can use [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=ios) for this...